# Remove line from dataframe based on date comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have currently two columns:

```
Current Date End Time

2015-07-17 08:55:00    Name: EndTime, data-type: datetime64[ns]

2015-07-14 23:45:00    Name: CurrentDate, data-type: datetime64[ns]
```

I would like to drop the lines in a dataframe `where (EndTime < CurrentDate)`.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
df2 = df2[pd.Series(df2['CurrentDate']) < pd.Series(df2['EndTime'])]
```

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
df2 = df2[(df2['CurrentDate']) <= (df2['EndTime'])]
```

No need to construct Series objects in place, you need parentheses around the conditions due to operator precedence